# How to pre-process this string?

Tags: python, data-preprocessing

I am working with a product data set for recommendations and I am trying to pre-process a string for keywords .

The string look like this and I am trying to get only the value portion of the string .

```
{"product_specification"=>[{"key"=>"Ideal For", "value"=>"Women"}, {"key"=>"Occasion", "value"=>"Casual"}, {"key"=>"Color", "value"=>"Red"}, {"key"=>"Outer Material", "value"=>"Patent Leather"}, {"key"=>"Heel Height", "value"=>"1 inch"}, {"key"=>"Number of Contents in Sales Package", "value"=>"Pack of 1"}, {"value"=>"One Pair Of Shoes"}]}
```

I want this string to be converted into a list of all values . For eg.

```
[Women, Casual, Red, Patent Leather, 1 inch, Pack of 1, One Pair Of Shoes]
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Where did that string come from? It looks like PHP syntax. Can't you fix the sender to use JSON?

Comment: You can do this: `values = [i.split('"')[2] for i in str(`Enter your string here`).split("value")[1:]]`.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is quite similar to a python dict, so after replacing `=>` with `:`, you can simply `eval` or `json.loads` to get the dictionary and then fetch its contents.

```
import json

str1 = '{"product_specification"=>[{"key"=>"Ideal For", "value"=>"Women"}, {"key"=>"Occasion", "value"=>"Casual"}, {"key"=>"Color", "value"=>"Red"}, {"key"=>"Outer Material", "value"=>"Patent Leather"}, {"key"=>"Heel Height", "value"=>"1 inch"}, {"key"=>"Number of Contents in Sales Package", "value"=>"Pack of 1"}, {"value"=>"One Pair Of Shoes"}]}'

str2 = str1.replace('=>', ':')
dikt = json.loads(str2)
items = dikt['product_specification']
result = [d['value'] for d in items]
print(result)  # ['Women', 'Casual', 'Red', 'Patent Leather', '1 inch', 'Pack of 1', 'One Pair Of Shoes']
```